# Why are OpenXR Actions only triggered by controller simulation?

Tags: windows-mixed-reality, openxr

I'm seeing strange behaviour with my OpenXR application, in that my action handling is fired correctly by the Windows Mixed Reality Portal controller simulators, but not by the controllers themselves.

This is clearly a broad question and I'm thinking I will probably answer it myself when I find the cause!

In the meantime suggestions on how where to look would be appreciated, of course.. !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will go down as one of the greats, I'm sure.

PUT THE HEADSET ON. No events are sent unless the headset is worn, or thinks it it being worn.